# global environmental variable not defined in .sh, but defined in console

Tags: macos, environment-variables, zsh

I'm using zsh, I have defined new global environmental variable in `~/.zshrc`

```
echo $0
-zsh
```

`echo $PATH_TO_BINARY` from console prints `/Users/user/some_path`

But if I create `run_me.sh` with content `echo $PATH_TO_BINARY` it prints nothing.

Same in python:

```
python -c "import os; print(os.environ['PATH_TO_BINARY'])"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/os.py", line 679, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'PATH_TO_BINARY'
```

Comment: So I guess the Python part is not relevant for the problem, is it?

Comment: I don't understand where `PATH_TO_BINARY` is supposed to be defined. Is `echo $0; -zsh` supposed to do that?

Comment: Which shell are you using in `run_me.sh`? Are you using zsh in the shebang? Or just `/bin/bash`?

Comment: When are you stabilishing the `PATH_TO_BINARY` env variable? Is it inside the .sh before calling python? If so python won't recognize it.

Comment: Unless you have a command like `export PATH_TO_BINARY` somewhere in `.zshrc` (and that should probably be in `.zprofile` instead), you don't *have* an *environment* variable named `PATH_TO_BINARY`; you just have an ordinary shell variable that won't be visible to any child processes, such as your Python script.

Comment: @mkrieger1 I define it in `~/.zshrc`

Comment: How about doing a `source ~/.zshrc` at the beginning of `run_me.sh` then? You have to get your definitions somehow into your script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't appear to have an environment variable. It sounds like you have a line like the following in `.zshrc`:

```
PATH_TO_BINARY=/Users/user/some_path
```

That's not an environment variable; it's just an ordinary shell variable. To add it to the environment (so that it will be passed to the environment of any child processes), you need to use the `export` command.

Add the following to your `.zprofile` file (not `.zshrc`):

```
export PATH_TO_BINARY=/Users/user/some_path
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. But I wonder why `echo $PATH_TO_BINARY` from shell still works?

Comment: Because the variable was defined in the shell; it just wasn't exported as an *environment* variable. They are two different things.